# Async for Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, collections, async-await

Is there a way to use async.each (or smth. like it) for an instance of Map collection to iterate over all key-value pairs on the collection and do smth for example call foo(key, value, cb) for each pair?

Comment: async.each(x.entries(), v=>console.log(v))  -> it does not work correctly

Comment: what about async.eachOf ?

Comment: You can declare an `async` function as an argument for your `map` function and then `await` the result of your function before proceeding

Comment: if `async.each` is a reference to the async library, then it has nothing to do with `async-await`

Comment: I have little experience with async, but according to the [docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), `each` can deal with any iterable Object so `async.each(yourMap, ([key, value], next) => { console.log(key, value); next(); })` should work